# Compute timedelta between two datetime.time instances

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to create a task manager with a spcefic time&task, while the date is irrelevant ( everyday reccurance ).

I'm trying to find the diff between times, e.g. `timedelta(hours=1)`:

```
datetime.time(13,00,00) - datetime.time(14,00,00)
```

ended with failture:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

while `datetime.date(2017,06,26) - datetime.date(2017,06,25)` ends well.

Comment: Please include sample code demonstrating the failure. It doesn't need to be all of your code, just something that shows why it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want the diff between the two dates or do you only want to know which date is larger or lower?

Comment: What's the expected result of "13:00 minus 14:00"?

Comment: yes, i'm intetested in diff result

Comment: So you want `timedelta(hours=1)` as result?

Comment: @deceze - i wish to know that there is 1 hrs left to run script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's `datetime` module doesn't let you calculate time deltas based on time-of-day only. That can result in ambiguities such as what to do when a sum is greater than 24 hours. In your case there is a hack that should work. Turn your times into `datetime` on the same day and do the math from there.

```
>>> def time_diff(t1, t2):
...     today = datetime.date.today()
...     return (datetime.datetime.combine(today, t1)
...         - datetime.datetime.combine(today, t2))
... 
>>> 
>>> time_diff(datetime.time(13,0,0), datetime.time(14,0,0))
datetime.timedelta(-1, 82800)
```

Negative `timedelta` looks weird (that's -1 days plus 82800 seconds) but should work in other calculations.

Comment: well... that's why timestamp was not enough. **thanks**

Comment: While running in PyCharm (script contains only time_diff above) answer is `0:05:00` Running the same time_diff on python console ( part of PyCharm ), answer is `datetime.timedelta(0, 300)`

Why the differnce ? more important - how can I get the answer (remaining time ) in seconds ?

Answer (score 2):

To get an answer in seconds, modify your code like this:

```
return (datetime.datetime.combine(today, t1)-datetime.datetime.combine(today, t2)).total_seconds()
```